# gitlab backup: make gitlab-rake produce tar.gz files not tar

Tags: backup, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

Backup files I get with `gitlab-rake` are tar files how can I get `tar.gz` ?

Here the files::

```
root@gitlab:~# ll /mnt/backup-git/ -h
total 1.9G
-rw------- 1 git  git   57M Nov 29 15:57 1480431448_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw------- 1 git  git   57M Nov 29 15:57 1480431473_gitlab_backup.tar
-rw------- 1 git  git  452M Nov 30 02:00 1480467623_gitlab_backup.tar
```

Here my configuration values for the backup::

```
$ grep -i backup /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb | grep -v '^#'
gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "/mnt/backup-git/"
gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800
```

To create them, following the documentation [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md), (omnibus installation):

```
root@gitlab:~# crontab -l | grep -v '^#'
0 2 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create CRON=1
```

Comment: Why not just gzip them?

Comment: Because in the https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md gitlab documentation they talk about "tar.gz" same here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/spec/tasks/gitlab/backup_rake_spec.rb

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really make sense to compress the gitlab backup tar files.  The gitlab backup tar files are the final tarball made during the backup process and the contents are all files compressed during the backup process.  You can read more [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25081)